# jquery-datatables export table to excel - Freeze Column/rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, export-to-excel

I'm trying to export a html table to excel using jquery datatables. I can fix the table head or columns using fixedheader or fixedcolumn plugin, but when exporting the table to excel corresponding rows/columns are not frozen. How to freeze columns /rows in exported excel?

Comment: What effort did you put already?

Comment: dataTables does not export plugin behaviour to Excel, exactly as Excel not exports fancy stuff when you export from Excel to CSV.